# Modify pg_hba.conf file to allow me access

Tags: linux, networking

I keep getting an error when trying to connect to psql database, "connection closed by remote host". I have tried modifying the pg_hba.conf file to allow the IP of my computer to have access, but I still get the same error, what am I doing wrong? Do I have to restart the server or something?

```
host all all <ip>/32 md5
```

As well, I have seen /24 instead of /32, how do I know which number to use?

Answer (score 0):

The notation "/32" refers to a single IP address whereas the notation "192.168.1.0/24" refers to all addresses on the 192.168.1.x network.

And yes, you will probably have to do an SQL restart, something like:

```
service postmaster restart
```

But make sure your IP address is restrictive so that hackers won't be visiting your database all day. Use "localhost" if you can (127.0.0.1).

Comment: I realized, I am using 192.168.0.0/16, but it is still not working. As well, I run /etc/init.d/postgresql restart, and I still am getting the same error of connection closed by remote host, I am confused as to what I have missed

Comment: To connect from other machine, you need to modify `postgresql.conf` as well. Search for `listen_addresses`, uncomment, add IP address of your postgresql machine. e.g.: `'localhost,192.168.0.5'`.

Comment: @tivn yes, I did, I changed it to listen_addresses = '*' with no results, I still get the same error

Comment: Have you restarted? Make sure it is listening on the interface, `0 0.0.0.0:5432` for `listen_addresses='*'`. Check with `netstat -ltn | grep -i listen | grep -w 5432`

Comment: Does postgresql use tcpwrappers? Is there need for an entry in hosts.allow? I assume the firewall port is open.

Comment: @Hankster postgresql does not seem to use tcpwrapper. Could be firewall / network issue.